# how to Update guid = "text"+post_name?

Tags: posts, guids

in phpmyadmin, i use this SQL command to update all posts that have guid like '%/?p=%' = "https:/bkfast.vn/"+post_name

[image: Update bkfast GUID]

`update lgs_posts set guid='https://bkfast.vn'&'post_name' where guid like '%/?p=%'`

But it's error: Truncated

Pls help me update all posts that have guid like '%/?p=%' = "https:/bkfast.vn/"+post_name

Old: https://bkfast.vn/p=2258 -> New: https://bkfast.vn/ky-thuat-trong-rau-thuy-canh-tinh

Info: post_name varchar(200); guid  varchar(255)

Comment: Why? The GUID is not the post’s URL. If you want to change your post URLs, use _Settings > Permalinks_.

Comment: i know Settings, Permalinks. But, i mean above command, how to write the correct command to run it ?

Comment: It’s not going to do anything though? There’s absolutely no reason to do this.

Comment: I think you meant `concat('https://bkfast.vn/', post_name)`. I don't think there's a simple string concat operator in MySQL, and you want post_name without the quotes to mean the post_name column.

Comment: If that's not it, please post the complete error you're getting.